# How to check sum of available values of the column = 0 in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel with column where the values are ranges from B2:B8, But first i am trying to use the filter then have to find SUM of the available column ranges

I have been using the code in VBA

Actual Data Table

```
S.No    T-Code       Value   Gcode    Status
1.       B220        2276     1
2.       AC55        2570     2
3.                  -2570     2
4.       D550       -5565     1
5.       N775        5565     1
6.       D887       -7797     3
7.                   2570     1
8.       D220       -2276     1
```

Script i have been using to use the Autofilter

```
Set shtFinal = wrkbok.Sheets(1)
Lastrow = shtFinal.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
shtFinal.Range("A1:Z" & Lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="1"
shtFinal.Range("A1:Z" & Lastrow).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>"
```

**Table after Filter**

```
S.No    T-Code       Value   Gcode   Status
1.       B220        2276     1
4.       D550       -5565     1
5.       N775        5565     1
8.       D220       -2276     1
```

Trying the Code to get the Expected output data

```
FilteredLastRow = shtFinal.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(shtFinal.Range("D2:D" & FilteredLastRow).Value) = 0 Then
shtFinal.Range("E2:E" & FilteredLastRow ).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "Matched"
End If
```

**Expected Output Data**

```
S.No    T-Code       Value   Gcode   Status
1.       B220        2276     1      Matched
4.       D550       -5565     1      Matched
5.       N775        5565     1      Matched
8.       D220       -2276     1      Matched
```

The below line of code is not working, instead of SUM only the visible rows it use to sum all the rows from 1 to 8 and the IF condition doesn't satisfies.

```
If Excel.WorksheetFunction.Sum(shtFinal.Range("D2:D" & FilteredLastRow).Value) = 0 Then
```

Please Suggest.

Comment: take a look at using sumifs instead of sum https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b

Comment: May I suggest a different approach? Why don't you save the items to an array/dictionary instead of filtering? It's way faster to iterate through items that way and you have more control over them

Answer (score 0):

We can Use Subtotal instead of Sum.

If We want total values only in visible rows, Subtotal 109 is the only option

By Modifying the below line of code it works.

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(109, shtFinal.Range("D2:D" & lngTemp)) = 0 Then
```